# How to keep my variable state as it is?

Tags: java, for-loop, static

Ok, So I have been making a Fibonacci Series program e.g(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21..). My logics are good but there is variable state problem when I come outside from the for() loop. 
How to keep my "firstNumber" state as it is ? 
And I dont know why it is printing value till 19 though I am giving input value 10

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        FibonacciFunction(input);

    }
    public static int FibonacciFunction(int x) {
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int i;
        for(i =1; i <= x; i++) {
            int numbers = firstNumber + i;
            System.out.println(numbers);
            firstNumber = i; //Keep this state as it is so that when loop run for the second time "firstNumber" should be 1 not 0 again


        }

        return firstNumber;
    }

}
```

**Output**
Enter the number: 
10
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19

Comment: what do you mean by state?

Comment: Do you mean how do you keep  it  equal to 0 after the method or how to make it not disappear after the method?  Or what does state mean?

Comment: "My logics are good" - you sure about that? Your program prints odd numbers instead of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: So you don't want `firstNumber` to change?  Then... don't assign a new value to it?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Though it's certainly clear that your output is not the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: You have more problems than that as well.  Your output should not include the number 5 for a while, 5 comes in the 6th row of the Fibb sequence not the 3rd.... you should google the fibb sequence first because your expected output is wrong as well..

Comment: Not to mention 19 isn't a part of the Fibb sequence at all...

Comment: Edit your question and get back to us, I would love to help just have to give us more info and have a better understanding of what you want/are asking.

Comment: @RostSunshine I mean, every time when loop runs "firstNumber" value should be firstNumber = firstNumber + i but it always ends with firstNumber = 0. I want to hold the value of firstNumber until the loop ends completely.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak According to mathematical way it is NextValue(8) = CurrentValue(5)+PreviousValue(3)

Comment: @LalitKumar so you are telling me that the FibbonacciFunction() returns 0 everytime?

Comment: @LalitKumar: `"but it always ends with firstNumber = 0"` - This implies that the loop is never entered *at all*.  `"I want to hold the value of firstNumber until the loop ends"` - What does that even *mean*?  Any variable you have is going to "hold its value" until you set it to another value.  Stop saying "I want to hold its value" and *specifically* describe the behavior you observe *as you step through in the debugger* and how that's different from what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is not correct: you are adding the iterator value `i` of the `for` loop to the last number, but you need to add the second-to-last number to the last number in the Fibonacci sequence. Thus, your `firstNumber` variable is not supposed to stay on the "state" of `1` or `0` but should grow with the Fibonacci sequence as the loop goes on.

```
public static int FibonacciFunction(int x) {
    if(x <= 0) return 0;
    int firstNumber = 0, secondNumber = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int numbers = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = numbers;
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }

    return firstNumber;
}
```

It's printing values up till 19 because the argument for the function is the number of Fibonacci values you want it to print, not the maximum Fibonacci number.

Answer (score -1):

To solve your error, you are saying that you want firstNumber to not be 0 when it comes out of the for loop.  It is impossible for firstNumber to be 0 at the end of the for loop unless the for loop didn't happen.  When you say it is coming back 0 that means the forloop is not going, in which case it returns the original value of firstNumber which is 0.  This means the value x is incorrect, or the way you read it in is incorrect.

Trying putting  in a S.O.P statement after  the `firstNumber =i;` to see what the value actually is:

```
   public static int FibonacciFunction(int x) {
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int i;
        for(i =1; i <= x; i++) {
            int numbers = firstNumber + i;
            System.out.println(numbers);
            firstNumber = i; 
            System.out.print(" First Number Value: "+ firstNumber);


        }

        return firstNumber;
    }
```